# Identifying duplicates in a table and kicking duplicate records to a another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have some employee records in my table and we are identifying duplicates in them based on one field called `workno`. My data in `TABLE_A` is shown below

```
NAME  WORKNO       DATE
---------------------------
John     30000  09-JAN-2012
Franklin 40000  08-DEC-2014
Alicia   25000  19-JUL-2013
Jennifer 43000  20-JUL-2015
Gary     38000  15-SEP-2016
Joyce    25000  31-JAN-2017
Ahmad    25000  29-MAR-2017
James    55000  10-APR-2017
Jill     43000  12-OCT-2017
Jack     55000  18-JAN-2018
```

**Imagine there are close to a million records here. So need help with efficiency**

My required output:-

*Scenario 1*: Keeping the records which has no duplicate(based on workno) in table_A itself. from the above table only John, Franklin and Gary should be there at the end since they have no duplicates with workno.

*Scenario 2*: the first record for a particular workno(incase of duplicates) should be written to table_B. "Alicia" with workno 25000 would be kicked into Table_B

*Scenario 3*: After writing the first duplicate to table_B the remaining records should be inserted into table_C. "Joyce" and "Ahmad" with workno would be kicked into table_C

I have tried to write my query which works fine for scenario 1 and 2. Need help if there is a better way if doing. But the insert part throws me error(query part works fine though).

Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
>   01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

```
Insert into ztempo
Select *
from (SELECT fname, minit, lname, bdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY salary ORDER BY rownum) num
      from  Select *
            from ztemp 
            where salary in (Select salary from ztemp group by salary having Count(*) > 1)

           )

     )
where num = 1;
```

I guess I can use the same code with some tweaking at the end "where num > 1" for scenario 3. But have problem inserting. Please help

Need help completing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be that the columns in `ztempo` are defined in a different order to the columns in your subquery. Try specifying the column lists explicitly.

Comment: Have you looked into triggers? This way you fix it at insert and never get duplicates. To go from  scenario 2 to 3: After placing a trigger on table_a place a second trigger on table_b to solve your problem.. All this get complicated to have in one query, and you have to run in often to keep the database “without” duplicates.

Comment: Hello Punnerud! I know it makes it easy. But these are log table and datas are erratic and can't catch the issue with trigger. Moreover with record close to a million these might hold up resources at different times. Am I right?

Comment: Hey William! yes the error is rectified now. Help me with the efficiency if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting suggests either the columns in `ztempo` are not the same order as `ztemp` or the date column is a varchar2 and contains invalid dates, like "2019-FEB-30".

It's better to explicitly state your columns, like this, in case the tables have the same columns, but in different order:

```
insert into ztempo ( fname, minit, ... )
```

You're grouping by salary in your subquery, is that really what you want to do? And I think the `order by rownum` clause pretty much does nothing.

Comment: Hello Ealson! That query isn't using actual data/or logic on that data. Was just playing with my own easy data. I know it doesn't make sense :P. Yes there was some with the format and the error is cleared now. I used the order by rownum to not disturb the order in which the duplicate record were available in the table since the first one is kicked into different table unlike the rest. Seems legit now? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

--SCENARIO 1: Deleting the duplicates from source table after inserting to other tables

```
Delete from table_a where workno in ( Select workno from table_a group by workno having count(*) > 1);
```

--SCENARIO 2: Inserting the first duplicate

```
Insert into table_b Select fname, Workno, ord_date
from
(
     SELECT fname, workno, ord_date, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workno ORDER BY rownum) num from
     (
     Select * from table_a 
     where workno in (
                      Select workno from table_a group by workno having count(*) > 1
                      )
      )
)
     where num = 1;
```

--SCENARIO 3: Inserting the other duplicate rows

```
Insert into table_c Select fname, Workno, ord_date
from
(
      SELECT fname, workno, ord_date, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workno ORDER BY rownum) num from
      (
      Select * from table_a 
      where workno in (
                       Select workno from table_a group by workno having count(*) > 1
                       )
       )
)
      where num > 1;
```

Is this the efficient way to go through a million records. Let me know if there is any other solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you've got it working, the only way to judge efficiency is with an execution plan. There are too many possible variables, otherwise, especially what indexes do you have. Also, how long does it take to run. How fast is "good enough" will vary with your requirements.